# Помогите разобраться с выводом изображения при помощи плагина Advanced Custom Fields (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin, acf

Таким способом выводит запись из поля:

```
<p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'contact1', true ); ?></p>
```

Таким способом выводит изображение:

```
<img alt='' src='<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/img/logo-el1.png'>
```

А вот изображение из поля НЕ выводит:

```
<image crs="
            <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 'slide1', 'full' );?>" 
       alt="slide1"/>
```

Так тоже не выводит:

```
<img alt='' src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/img/<?php esc_url( the_field( 'slide1' ) );?>"/> 
<img alt='' src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/<?php esc_url( the_field( 'slide1' ) );?>"/>
<img alt='' src="<?php esc_url( the_field( 'slide1' ) );?>"/>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его вывести?

Answer (score 1):

Код

```
<image crs="
        <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 'slide1', 'full' );?>" 
   alt="slide1"/>
```

исправьте на

```
<img src="
        <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );?>" 
   alt="slide1"/>
```

Если Вы хотите вывести все вложения, то вам необходимо использовать код следующего содержения

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    ) );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            ?>
<img src="
    <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );?>"
alt="slide1"/>
            <?php
        }
    }
endwhile; endif;?>
```

Comment: спасибо, что Вы подметили, но и это НЕ сработало, к сожалению...проблема не в этом...

Comment: вы также должны указать ID загруженного изобржения

Comment: <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id->ID, 'full' );?> так тоже не срабатывает...

Comment: Обновил ответ, чтобы выводить все вложения

Comment: мне нужно в определенном месте вывести определенное изображение, как определенный текст, в определенном месте. /img/logo-el1.png заменить на код, который вытянет это изображение при вводе через поле ACF

Answer (score 1):

Поля ACF выводятся с помощью [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) и [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/). Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
<img alt='' src='<?php esc_url( the_field( 'image' ) );?>'>
```

где `'image'` - слаг (имя) вашего поля ACF.

Comment: добавил все возможные вариации, но все равно не работает почему-то...

Comment: <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?> - без этой строки файлы не находятся

Comment: все зависит от того, что вы записываете в поле

Comment: имя поля: slide1, тип поля:  изображение.

Comment: что выводит `var_dump( get_field( 'slide1' ) )`?

Comment: bool (false) выводит

Comment: Значит, поле пустое, значение ему не задано. Или же поле не относится к текущей записи/странице. У вас нечто такое вот задано? http://take.ms/GGE1m В общем, покажите настройки группы полей, вы там что-то делаете неправильно.

Comment: я заполнил, как и текстовые поля, которые работают.
На изображение поставил на всех страницах
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B37oNxRT53I0V2tkQXFURzNXN0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: У вас что возвращается в этом поле? Должно быть так: http://take.ms/H4pqA

Comment: да, у меня именно так и стоит "ссылка на изображение"